# How can I use sprintf() for print to a char *?

Tags: c, memory-management, concatenation, c-strings

I am doing a c program for an university project. I have the nex code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

...

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ...
    char * resolve = 0;
    sprintf(resolve, "%s,%s\n", HTTP_HEADER, ERR_404);
    printf("%s", resolve);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting Segmentation Fault in the line of the sprintf, Is somehow manner to get this work.
P.D: HTTP_HEADER and ERR_404 are strings defined.

Comment: Roughly `char * resolve = 0;` -> `char resolve[100]`

Comment: Looks like, if you wanted to, you can call `snprintf` with a length of `0` and it'll tell you how long the string would be, if it was to write it.  You can then allocate memory for the string if you wanted the size to be exact.

Comment: @DevSolar hmm, fair enough I guess. Is this some new(ish) policy or are you just the first one to point that out to me in all those years?

Comment: It's right there in [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) -- "Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer." StackOverflow is the most lenient of the StackExchange sites in this, the other stacks pay much more attention to it, to the point of comments being moderated away once they outlived their usefulness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pointer `resolve` points to NULL.  When it is passed to `sprintf`, the function attempts to dereference that pointer.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes the program to crash.

Define `resolve` to instead be an array large enough to hold the resulting string.

```
char resolve[1000];
sprintf(resolve, "%s,%s\n", HTTP_HEADER, ERR_404);
```

Alternately, you can call `snprintf` with a NULL pointer and a size of 0.  This will return the number of characters that would be written to the string.  You can then allocate exactly that much space (plus 1 for the null terminating byte) and call `snprintf` again.

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s,%s\n", HTTP_HEADER, ERR_404);
char resolve[len+1];
snprintf(resolve, len, "%s,%s\n", HTTP_HEADER, ERR_404);
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it work using the minimum space required.

Answer (score 1):

As the pointer resolve is a null pointer then using it to write to memory invokes undefined behavior.

You should allocate enough space where you are going to write the two strings.

It can be done the following way.

```
size_t n = strlen( HTTP_HEADER );

char *resolve = malloc( n + strlen( ERR_404 ) + 3 );

strcpy( resolve, HTTP_HEADER );
resolve[n] = ',';

++n;

strcpy( resolve + n, ERR_404 );
strcat( resolve + n, "\n" );

printf("%s", resolve);

//...

free( resolve );
resolve = NULL;
```

Comment: I assume that the `+3` in the malloc argument is covering the comma, the newline and the terminating null byte. I'm wondering though whether it's possible that on DOS or MS Windows a CR-NL pair is appended (or whether this is handled only when writing to a terminal).

Comment: Another potential issue could arise if the program is executed in a utf locale and the headers contain 8 bit ascii characters, e.g. German umlauts. In that case the printed bytestream, which could contain multi-byte characters, would be longer than expected. To be on the safe side with both issues I'd prefer dbush's suggestion to perform a test snprintf first in order to obtain the output size at run time depending on the environment.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You are right it is for ',', '\n' and '\0' characters. It is the system that should convert the new line character to appropriate characters.

Comment: " It is the system that should convert the new line character to appropriate characters": And if it does, you overflow the allocated memory.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica He uses character arrays not multibyte characters.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica There is neither overflowing. It is a work of the output functions. It has nothing with the memory occupied by a string.

Comment: "He uses character arrays not multibyte characters": *He* does, but does the local version of printf? I suspect the space needed in buf for `sprintf(buf, "ü\n")` is locale and system dependent and can be between 3 and 5 bytes.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica In this case he needs to use another function. And moreover the memory allocated according to the values returned by the function strlen. So what are the lengths of the strings is what  how much memory will be allocated.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the size needed for `sprintf(buf, "ü\n")` doesn't depend on the locale but on the encoding of your source file. and in every case `strlen( "ü" )` will return the number of bytes used to represent the Umlaut (2 if your source is UTF-8, 1 if it's CP-1252 or similar)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Source file dependency: I noticed that, too, when I experimented. So the locale influences things like the decimal sign, but not the encoding? Or is it that strings (arguments corresponding to "%s", or the format string proper) are always considered literal byte sequences? Or, if I have a terminal expecting utf-8, is it the terminal driver doing the translation?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica indeed there are no code translation done in stdio.h or string.h functions at all.  By regarding the facts that C strings are just char arrays and sizeof char is 1 by definition it's quite clear that any function you pass such a string has no knowledge about the encoding. E.g. If you select an appropriate sequence of CP-1252 characters they could also forn a valid UTF-8 multibyte sequence. So yes, they are always considered literal byte sequences.